# Cypress Docker: Chrome was not found on your sysyem

Tags: docker, cypress

I'm trying to run my Cypress tests in a docker container locally but I keep having an issue when trying to run in Chrome, the command I'm running is:

```
docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:10.3.1 --browser chrome
```

According to https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/included it should have chrome, firefox and edge but I'm getting:

> Can't run because you've entered an invalid browser name.
>
> Browser: chrome was not found on your system or is not supported by
> Cypress.
>
> Cypress supports the following browsers:
>
> - electron
> - chrome
> - chromium
> - chrome:canary
> - edge
> - firefox
>
> You can also use a custom browser:
> https://on.cypress.io/customize-browsers
>
> Available browsers found on your system are:
>
> - electron

Locally I do have Chrome and Firefox installed. I'm able to run the tests through docker using Electron fine, but I'm trying to run a lighthouse test which requires running on Chrome.

Am I doing something wrong? I've tried another few cypress/included v 10 images but haven't had any luck. I'm running on a Macbook if that makes any difference.

If I don't use docker and just open Cypress I'm able to run on Chrome fine.

Comment: Disclaimer: not familiar with this tooling but the docs you link to have a sneaky extra 'run' in the command that is executed, because two runs are better than one. `docker run -it -v $PWD:/e2e -w /e2e cypress/included:10.3.1 run --browser chrome` . Perhaps that is just a typo in your question?

Comment: Thanks @Gimby, I just tried that but I got the same output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your processor architecture is arm64 the cypress/browser docker image does not contain any browsers.

The reason is following line in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN node -p "process.arch === 'arm64' ? 'Not downloading Chrome since we are on arm64: https://crbug.com/677140' : process.exit(1)" ||
```

Cypress has already commented on this and asks to support this architecture. See here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677140#c19

Comment: Thanks, yeah I’m using an M1 cpu, should have guessed I’ve had other issues around android studio on the this MacBook too